# time data '2023-04-15T16:22:03.721461+05:00' does not match format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+%Z'"

Tags: python, django, templatetags

I get my data from drf as json and ther my datetime looks like:

```
              `'2023-04-15T16:22:03.721461+05:00'`
```

but i want show datetime in template like:

```
                `'15-04-2023 16:22'`
```

so i use tamplatetag:

```
# app/templatetags/event_extras.py
@register.filter(expects_localtime=True)
def parse_iso(value):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+%Z'")
```

and html like:

```
{% load event_extras %}

<th>{{r.datetime|parse_iso}|date:'d/m/Y H:M'}</th>
```

but got this error:
`time data '2023-04-15T16:22:03.721461+05:00' does not match format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+%Z'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the timezone in your test string is specified as an offset not as a timezone string, you have to parse it with `%z` format specifier, not `%Z` in your original post. Also you do not want to put the sign in the format string:

```py
def parse_iso(value):
   return datetime.datetime.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
```

This would parse your string as

```
>>> parse_iso('2023-04-15T16:22:03.721461+05:00')
datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 15, 16, 22, 3, 721461, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=18000)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the last character in the string, it's probably ruining the convertion:

```
return datetime.datetime.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+%Z'")
```